# Linq Query - Order By field(string type - should converted in to int) - for each group

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, c#-4.0

Code:

```
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(u => u.state)
                                            .OrderBy(grp => StateToOrder(grp.Key))
                                            .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                                            .ToList();
```

Above code groups the records and displaying the result. I want a field(`rank`) which is of type `string` which should be converted to `int` and applied to the sorted group `state` in which, each `state` group should display the records based on the `rank` field(`ascending order`).

In short, I need to add the `rank` field to the above code for displaying the records in `rank`(`ascending order`) for each `state` group.

I need to order the records based on `rank` for each group `state`.
I don't know where and how to add the `rank` field in the above code. Say for example, `rank` fields has the values (1, 2,3,....etc.,) which is of type `string`.

Comment: I think some sample input/output would help here.

Comment: say for example, rank fields has the values (1, 2,3,....etc.,) which is of type string

Comment: I need to order the records based on `rank` for each group `state`

Comment: I don't know where and how to add the rank field in the above code

Comment: try: `OrderBy(grp => grp.rank)`

Comment: @UmairM, After / Before, what line i need to add the `OrderBy(grp => grp.rank)` code ?. Also, `rank` field is in `string` type.

Comment: @StackOverflow why is it a string field? Can't you expose it as an `int`? It sounds like you need an abstraction somewhere that will provide you the fields as you need them.

Comment: @AntP, It is in string type as it is an API service field. We just use that API values in our application.

Comment: Replace your original `OrderBy()` by this one if you dont want to use that. Or if you want to use both then you should use `ThenBy()` with same lambda operation in it after `OrderBy()`.

Comment: @UmairM, ie..`list.GroupBy(u => u.state)
                                            .OrderBy(grp => StateToOrder(grp.Key)).ThenBy(grp => grp.rank).Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                                            .ToList();` Is that correct ? Is that String type properly display records in ascending order ?

Comment: yes it is correct and self explanatory

Comment: @UmairM, After `grp.`, rank is not displayed in the intellisense.

Comment: @StackOverflow `grp` is doesn't have the `rank` properties, `grp` is `IGrouping`, so it has a key and list of elements. Each one of these elements has a 'rank` property. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the list in each group by `rank` :

```
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(u => u.state)
                      .OrderBy(grp => StateToOrder(grp.Key))
                      .Select(grp =>
                      new
                      {
                          grp.Key,
                          Data = grp.OrderBy(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.rank)
                                                  ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(x.rank))
                      });

foreach(var g in groupedList)
{
    g.Key; // Key;
    g.Data; // Ordered List for that state
}
```

If you want to place the record with empty rank at the end, replace

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.rank) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(x.rank)
```

with

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.rank) ? Int32.MaxValue : Convert.ToInt32(x.rank)
```

Comment: I tried your answer and got `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'AnonymousType#1'` error

Comment: @StackOverflow At what line are you having this error ?

Comment: @StackOverflow don't use `g[0]` use `d.Data.ElementAt(0);`

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Actually accessing `count`, i got this error

Comment: @StackOverflow inside the foreach, you can do `g.Data.Count()`

Comment: How to check the `rank` is not empty because, i am getting `input string was not correct` error message in foreach at `count`

Comment: If it is empty, then it can be considered as `0`. Then it will be correct..How to do in that query in the `convert.toint32`?

Comment: @StackOverflow where do you to place the value in the order if it is empty ?

Comment: I am trying with this `Data = grp.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32((x.rank != "" ? x.rank : "0"))) ` ..Lets see..

Comment: Thank You very much..Working fine as expected. Thanks for your time and effort..)